# Load Country -> State -> City depencency in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

How can we create dependent selection of Country->State->City in Odoo?

- For example -

  - Selected Country = United States

    - which will load All state of US
  - State = Texas, California, Ohio, .. etc,

    - Selected state = Texas
    - On Selection of State, it will load all Cities in selected state.
  - City = Austin, Huston, ..etc.

How can we achieve this in Odoo?

I have created below code in model.py

```py
country = fields.Many2one('res.country',string='Country', help='Select Country')
state = fields.Many2one('state.country',string='State', help='Enter State')
city = fields.Char('City', help='Enter City')
```

view.xml file is having just below code:

```xml
<field name="country"/>
<field name="state"/>
<field name="city"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
state_id = fields.Many2one("res.country.state", string='State', help='Enter State', ondelete='restrict')
country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country', string='Country', help='Select Country', ondelete='restrict')    
city = fields.Char('City', help='Enter City')
hide = fields.Boolean(string='Hide', compute="_compute_hide")

# Dependent picklist code to show State based on selected Country E.g India -> Gujarat, Maharastra, Rajasthan, etc..
@api.onchange('country_id')
def _onchange_country_id(self):
    if self.country_id:
        return {'domain': {'state_id': [('country_id', '=', self.country_id.id)]}}
    else:
        return {'domain': {'state_id': []}}

# Show Hide State selection based on Country
@api.depends('country_id')
def _compute_hide(self):
    if self.country_id:
        self.hide = False
    else:
        self.hide = True

# view.xml
<field name="hide" invisible="1"/>
<field name="country_id" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create_edit' : True}"/>
<field name="state_id" options="{'no_quick_create': True, 'no_create_edit' : True}" attrs="{'invisible':[('hide', '=', True)]}"/>
<field name="city"/>
```